# Set IIS website Classic ASP session timeout using Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, asp-classic

How do I set the Classic ASP Session timeout in IIS 8.5 using powershell?

I've taken a look at using `Set-WebConfigurationProperty` but can't work out how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webServer/asp/session -Name timeout -Value 00:05:00
```

Link(s)

- Jeong's Blog - IIS Powershell User guide - Comparing representative IIS UI tasks https://blogs.iis.net/jeonghwan/iis-powershell-user-guide-comparing-representative-iis-ui-tasks